Vectors are drawn incorrectly in python matplotlib
I need to write a program to draw an array of vectors. I have written the following code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

vectors = [
    [-1, 0, 1, 0],
    [9, 0, 11, 0],
    [0, 9, 0, 11],
    [10, 9, 10, 11]
]

for vector in vectors:
    plt.quiver(vector[0], vector[1], vector[2], vector[3])

plt.grid(True)
plt.show()


The vectors are rendered incorrectly and something strange happened to the vector at the top right.
I tried to rewrite the program where I drew vectors one by one, but still the result were the same.

Can you explain what each value in the row represents? The first two points are where the tail should be and the last two are...?

Coordinates, where the end of the vector should be directed to

By default, angles="uv", which uses the U and V arguments to just determine the direction of the arrow. What you want is angles="xy", which the documentation says:

'xy': Arrow direction in data coordinates, i.e. the arrows point from (x, y) to (x+u, y+v). Use this e.g. for plotting a gradient field.

Since your last two values in each vector are the coordinates for the endpoint, you need to subtract the starting values since matplotlib is expecting U and V to be dx and dy.
To make sure they are scaled correctly, follow what the documentation says for the scale_units argument:

To plot vectors in the x-y plane, with u and v having the same units as x and y, use angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1

So, here is how your code should look.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close("all")

vectors = [
    [-1, 0, 1, 0],
    [9, 0, 11, 0],
    [0, 9, 0, 11],
    [10, 9, 10, 11]
]

for vector in vectors:
    print(vector[0], vector[1], vector[2] - vector[0], vector[3] - vector[1],)
    plt.quiver(vector[0], vector[1],
               vector[2] - vector[0], vector[3] - vector[1],
               angles="xy", scale_units="xy", scale=1)
plt.xlim(-2, 12)
plt.ylim(-1, 12)
plt.grid()
plt.show()


